# Android Studio Submit on Carriage Return

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating an app for Android using Android Studio that uses a Motorola CS3000 barcode scanner. It is in HID mode (emulating keyboard), and each scan it inputs a series of keys, and ends with a carriage return.

I am using onEditorActionListener to trigger the event, and am wondering how to trigger said event through a carriage return from the scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

    if (event != null && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

        case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // for some reason we can get tons of repeated down events in the debugger, maybe from keyboard auto-repeat?
            return true;

        case KeyEvent.ACTION_UP:

            // *** put your event code here ***

            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! I'd be grateful if you would accept my answer as correct.  Cheers

Comment: Just did. First time asking a question, so I didn't realize the check mark was for that.